# Checkbox-Hack not working inside of table

Tags: html, css

Because it's easier to explain when you have seen it, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kofh5vs4/1/).

#### Description

I have a table with `thead` and `tbody`. Now I wanted to use the checkbox-hack inside the table to "select" rows. However when opening the devtools on the site, you can see that the `input` is on top of the table, moved outside of the table by the browser on page load.

#### Some code

```
<!--
                                                  moved up
<input type="checkbox" id="generated-id">    <--------------+
                                                            |    -->
                                                   <!--     |    -->
<table>                                            <!--     |    -->
    <thead>                                        <!--     |    -->
        <th>columns</th>                           <!--     |    -->
        ...                                        <!--     |    -->
    </thead>                                       <!--     |    -->
                                                   <!--     |    -->
    <tbody>                                        <!--     |    -->
        <input type="checkbox" id="generated-id">  <!--  ---+    -->

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="generated-id">
                    highlight this row
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Question

Is there any way I can use the checkbox-hack inside a table? Just to point this out, I could use JS, but this would make it unusable for users without JS (and those sadly exist).

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but have you actually read my question? Putting the checkbox in a `td` would solve the problem of it being moved, but would completely remove the checkbox-hack possibilty which this question actually addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, you cannot use [the checkbox-hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) inside a table

You answered the question with your comment above:

> Putting the checkbox in a `td` would solve the problem of it being moved, but would completely remove the checkbox-hack possibilty…

### But…

*You can use an alternative CSS-only hack to apply styles to an entire row based on user selection.*

By using the `:focus` pseudo-class in conjunction with a general sibling selector `~`, and applying `tabindex="0"` to one (or all) of the `td` elements in a row, the entire row — in effect — can be styled based on user interaction.

A user can click and even tab through the rows to highlight them.

**For example:**

```css
td[tabindex] { cursor: pointer; }
td:focus,
td:focus ~ td {
    background-color: Tomato;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>column 1</th>
        <th>column 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td tabindex="0">
                highlight this row
            </td>
            <td>
                Some text in a cell
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. You're right, I kinda answered it in my comment, but I wasn't aware that it isn't possible. Your answer would work, if I only had to highlight 1 single row. However, as I wrote, I need to *"select" rows*, so this solution won't work either. If nobody comes up with another solution I'm going to mark this as an answer.

Comment: I see. This is not suitable for multiple selection. It's no substitute for the CBH. However, you could use the checkbox hack if each row only included one `td` which had the `input` and a nested table inside of it.  The nested table would have exactly one row, but multiple cells and could be styled as necessary. But using nested tables is messy and comes with its own unique caveats.

Comment: Well, nested tables would be another aproach, but then I'd be as far as I was at the beginning with a responsive grid, messy and slower as there are **many** entries in the table.

Comment: Since nobody came up with an answer yet I'll mark this one as the accepted answer, because gfullam mentioned it wasn't possible. My problem is now solved via Javascript, however I'd still be happy if someone comes up with a CSS only solution.

Comment: I think JavaScript is the way to go. There is a good Q&A on UX StackExchange: [Should i optimize my website for non-javascript users?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45229/should-i-optimize-my-website-for-non-javascript-users) The accepted answer, with which I agree, concludes that "Javascript has become a standard of the web" and that the ever fewer users who disable it "do it by choice…"; so, "this isn't an accessibility issue". Build your site for your target base with a consideration for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) HTML element encapsulates a set of table rows (`<tr>` elements). Any other element will be put out of the `table` markup. However, if you still insist on putting a `checkbox` under a `<tbody>`, then you need the following CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + table tr {
    background-color: #000;
}
```